# Remove Telerik MVC DropList Item via Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I am trying to remove an item from my telerik MVC dropList with Jquery.  It seems that the conventional approach does not work...

$("#Type option[value='02']").remove();

Is there any way to remove an item from this dropList control?

Thank you

Comment: More information required to figure out what's going on here. Even the relevant markup would be a help.

Comment: works fine for me: [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roselan/mvyU6/1/)

Comment: I'm not sure what I else I would need to provide.  I just need to remove an item from the list.  With a regular droplist the code specified above will remove the item, but with telerik mvc extension this doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: @roselan I'm using a telerik mvc extension.  This is a regular select.

Comment: well, after looking at telerik demos, their native "select" boxes are not select tags at all, but lists ("ul" tags), and the option tags are list elements ("li"...)

Answer (score 0):

apprently, telerik uses lists and a bunch of css to create "virtual" selects.

```
$("#Type li:contains('02')").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roselan/mvyU6/2/

Comment: Gave this a try and no dice... Thank you for taking the time to help out but I'm going to just use a regular dropList in this particular view. I've already spent far too much time on this issue..

Comment: my guess is that the list id is not "type", try to replace "#type" with "ul" in the selector, if you still have time.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, there is no consistent way to richly style and customize HTML `<select>` elements. That is why the Telerik Combobox for MVC does not directly use this element.

Instead, the Combobox uses a rich client-side object, HTML, and CSS, and "binds" to data that defines your list of options. Rather than hacking at the Combobox HTML to visually remove an item, a better approach is to use the Combobox API.

You can use code like this to remove elements from the data array bound to the Combobox:

```
//Get the Telerik Combobox client-side object    
var comboBox = $("#ComboBox").data("tComboBox");
//Get the array of objects bound to the drop down list
var ds = comboBox.data;
//Rebind (and in turn, re-render) the drop down after modifying the source array
comboBox.dataBind(ds.splice(1,1));
```

Where in this example, only 1 item will be left in your Combobox dropdown.

Hope this helps.